# jQuery Canvas unexpected result

Tags: jquery, canvas

Running the following returns 2 calls, but the first call has BOTH canvas items on the console.log.

1) Why does this happen
2) How do I stop it!

```
$.fn.DonutIt = function( options ){
    var settings = $.extend({
        color: "#600", 
        bgColor: "#000", 
        percentage: 50, 
        fontColor: "#000", 
        fontSize: "14px", 
        fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    }, options );

    var canvas = this;
    console.log(canvas);
};

}( jQuery));
window.onload = function(){
    $("canvas").DonutIt({percentage: 99.5});    
$("donutOTIF").DonutIt({percentage: 50});   
};

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100">
<canvas id="donutOTIF" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Your plugin doesn't do anything, and the second call certainly doesn't do anything as ID's start with `#`? And why would you use a window.onload handler !

Comment: @adeneo, the actual plugin code was removed to reduce bloat and I never saw the # was missing!! DOH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("canvas")` Selects all elements with the `canvas` tag name.[Read more...](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Also
To `extend` jquery `functions` you should use `jQuery.fn.extend`.

> The `jQuery.fn.extend()` method extends the jQuery prototype
>   `($.fn)` object to provide new methods that can be chained to the
>   `jQuery()` function.

`return this.each` help you to merge your commands and you can call more functions by one select.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    DonutIt: function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var defaults = {
                color: "#600",
                bgColor: "#000",
                percentage: 50,
                fontColor: "#000",
                fontSize: "14px",
                fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
            };
            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            var canvas = this;
            console.log(canvas);
            console.log(settings.percentage);
        });
    }
});
//canvas and donutOTIF get percentage=99.5
$("#canvas,#donutOTIF").DonutIt({
    percentage: 99.5
});
//donutOTIF get percentage=50
$("#donutOTIF").DonutIt({
    percentage: 50
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/LvL117ao/1/)

Comment: many thanks for the info on extend, can't believe i didn't spot the missing #'s DOH!  It's been a llloooonnnnngggg day!

Answer (score 1):

`$()` uses CSS selectors. `$("#someID")` will select an element of `someID`, and doing `$("canvas")` will select all canvas elements.

#### JS

```
$.fn.DonutIt = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
        color: "#600", 
        bgColor: "#000", 
        percentage: 50, 
        fontColor: "#000", 
        fontSize: "14px", 
        fontFamily: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    }, options);
    var canvas = this;
    console.log(canvas);
};

$.ready(function(){
    $("#canvas").DonutIt({percentage: 99.5});    
    $("#donutOTIF").DonutIt({percentage: 50});   
});
```

#### HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<canvas id="donutOTIF" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

And FYI, `<canvas>` is not a self-closing tag *nor* does it not require a closing tag.

Comment: actually $('canvas') will work just fine, it will search for the tag name instead of the id. It'll select both canvases